# switch statement Error : Statement must be prepended with case label

Tags: android, switch-statement

Hello I have a switch statement , I want to save the `intent.getIntExtra("Position",0)` value to `Position` variable however when I do it give me the mentioned error , Here's my Code

```
if(intent.getIntExtra("HandyLevel",0)==1 && SharedPreferenceStuff.getLevel(getApplicationContext())>=1) //Preface
        {
            HandyLevel = intent.getIntExtra("HandyLevel",0);
            switch (intent.getIntExtra("Position",0))
            {
                int Positions = intent.getIntExtra("Position",0);

                case 2: //History
                    if(intent.getStringExtra("Divider").equals("Q1History" )) {

                        if(goToNextLevel) {
                            if (SharedPreferenceStuff.getSubLevel(getApplicationContext()) == 3)
                                SharedPreferenceStuff.setSubLevel(getApplicationContext(), 4);
                            localIntent = new Intent(QuestionFrame.this, LevelOne.class);
                            localIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                            startActivity(localIntent);
                            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_start_from_button, R.anim.slide_to_up);
                        }
                        else Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"FUCCCK",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    break;
              }
          }
```

What should i do ? Thanks

Comment: Why are you using the switch statement? Isn't a switch with one case just an over complicated if statement?

Comment: put `int Positions = intent.getIntExtra("Position",0);` under the `case 2` statement

Comment: yes it is , but this is not whole of my code , i just copy a piece of it :) @Ryry

Comment: Thanks @SamuelRobert Post it then i Accept it as the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @Samuel Roberts says in the comments, you need to move:

```
int Positions = intent.getIntExtra("Position",0);
```

either inside your `case 2` (and therefore possibly in your other cases too) or outside of your `switch`. The error you're getting is saying "you can only have a `case` statement inside a `switch`, other statements are not allowed without being inside a `case`".

Please see the documentation here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
if(intent.getIntExtra("HandyLevel",0)==1 && SharedPreferenceStuff.getLevel(getApplicationContext())>=1) //Preface
    {
        HandyLevel = intent.getIntExtra("HandyLevel",0);
        int Positions = intent.getIntExtra("Position",0);
        switch (intent.getIntExtra("Position",0))
        {
             case 2: //History
                if(intent.getStringExtra("Divider").equals("Q1History" )) {

                    if(goToNextLevel) {
                        if (SharedPreferenceStuff.getSubLevel(getApplicationContext()) == 3)
                            SharedPreferenceStuff.setSubLevel(getApplicationContext(), 4);
                        localIntent = new Intent(QuestionFrame.this, LevelOne.class);
                        localIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(localIntent);
                        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_start_from_button, R.anim.slide_to_up);
                    }
                    else Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"FUCCCK",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                break;
          }
      }
```

Try this